How to Make Fade Out Particle in Flame?
I was able to create a particle that shows text when tapped using the code below. Is it possible to make this particle fade out? (in this question, by "fade out," I mean adjusting the opacity.)
import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flame/particles.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const FooApp());
}

class FooApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const FooApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: GameWidget.controlled(gameFactory: TextGame.new),
    );
  }
}

class TextGame extends FlameGame {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();

    await add(
      ButtonComponent(
        position: Vector2(size.x * 0.5, size.y * 0.5),
        onPressed: () {
          add(
            ParticleSystemComponent(
              position: Vector2(size.x * 0.5, size.y * 0.5),
              particle: AcceleratedParticle(
                lifespan: 2.0,
                speed: Vector2(0, 50),
                child: ComponentParticle(
                  component: TextComponent(
                    anchor: Anchor.center,
                    text: "Taped!",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        button: TextComponent(
          text: 'B',
          textRenderer: TextPaint(
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 88,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        anchor: Anchor.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}


References:

https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/flame/rendering/particles.html
https://flame.tnantoka.com/examples/text/#text
https://flame.tnantoka.com/examples/button/#button


Yes! You can implement your own custom particle and use its update method to change the opacity.
For example, you can extend CircleParticle and provide an implementation to slowly reduce the opacity until it reaches zero.
class MyParticle extends CircleParticle {
  MyParticle({required super.paint});

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);

    final newAlpha = (paint.color.a - 0.5 * dt).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
    paint.color = paint.color.withValues(alpha: newAlpha);
  }
}

You can also play around with composition with other Particles, using Flutter's Curves for non-linear behaviour, and much more.
As a more complete example, this implementation fires a burst of red particles that then fade out.
